# How to paginate in eager loading?

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, eager-loading

I have posts and comments tables. Post and Comment have one-to-many relationship.

```
$posts = Post::with(array('comments' => function($c) {
          $c->paginate(5);
     }, 'comments.user'))->paginate(10);
```

But I can't evaluate the links for comments with the following code:

```
$post->comments->links();
```

This gives the following error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links

How can I evaluate comment links?

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand why you are using paginate in your closure, makes no sense.

Please try.

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->paginate(10);
```

The `$posts` data will have everything you need as long as you have got the correct relationships setup.

Comment: As per your comment only posts are paginated.I want comments also to be paginated as example(consider facebook as an example)